# Point / Credit system

Tags: magento-1.8

I am after a credit system extension which will allow customers to purchase products using points however we completely want to remove prices and only display number of points it costs. Does any one know of an extension that will do this?

Comment: Where do the points come from?

Comment: From the chosen extension the admin would manually update the number of points a customer has